# WebException using reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to connect to ReportingServices through the ASP.NET web ReportViewer control:

```
               rvContract.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
            rvContract.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials("myUsername", "myNetworkPassword", "DOMAIN");
            rvContract.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ReportConfiguration.ReportServerUrl);
            string rptPath = ReportConfiguration.RootPath;
            if (!rptPath.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                rptPath += "/";
            }
            rvContract.ServerReport.ReportPath = rptPath + "AdminReports/Contract";

            List<ReportParameter> reportParams = new List<ReportParameter>();

            if (MkoSession.AccountId.HasValue)
            {
                ReportParameter accountId = new ReportParameter("AccountId", MkoSession.AccountId.Value.ToString());
            }

            rvContract.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParams);

            rvContract.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
            rvContract.ShowZoomControl = false;

            rvContract.ServerReport.Refresh();
            rvContract.DataBind();
```

The implementation of the credentials looks like this:

```
public class ReportServerCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
{
    private string _userName;
    private string _password;
    private string _domain;

    public ReportServerCredentials(string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        _userName = userName;
        _password = password;
        _domain = domain;
    }

    public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
    {
        get
        {
            // Use default identity.
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
        get
        {
            // Use default identity.
            return new NetworkCredential(_userName, _password, _domain);
        }
    }

    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user, out string password, out string authority)
    {
        // Do not use forms credentials to authenticate.
        authCookie = null;
        user = null;
        password = null;
        authority = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just hard-coding my credentials while testing.  Before check-in, we'll have to create a domain account for this.

I can hit both ReportService2005.asmx and ReportExecution2005.asmx (which is what my ReportServerUrl becomes) no problem through a browser.

When I get to the SetParameters call, I get a WebException.  Looking at the headers in the Response within the Exception:

{RSNotAuthenticated: True
RSAuthenticationHeader: .ASPXFORMSAUTH
Content-Length: 206
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 16:15:08 GMT
Location: /ReportServer/logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2freportserver%2fReportExecution2005.asmx
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727

}

which seems as if it's telling me that I haven't logged in.  If that's the case, how do the *exact same credentials* allow me to see the web services through a browser?

BTW, I did set breakpoints in each of the methods in my ReportServerCredentials implementation and saw each breakpoint hit.  Not sure what that's telling us, but the NetworkCredentials interface returned my network credentials just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might've stumbled into it.  In case anyone else is having similar troubles.

First, I poked around and found the reporting services web.config on the server.  Saw that it was using authenticaion mode = forms.

So, then I implemented the GetFormsCredentials to return true and pass a generic username.  I got this username out of the Users table in the ReportServer database.

No longer getting the WebException, but my ReportViewer isn't displaying either.  So, not out of the woods yet, but it seems closer.

FWIW, I *think* I remember somebody saying we had weird custom forms authentication on our db server.   So, for anybody who happens upon this, YMMV.  All of that predates me, so I'm not really sure how to check it out.